# Compile guide for UKUI?

Tags: compiling, kylin

Is there a compile guide for UKUI? It's the desktop environment for Ubuntu Kylin. I've tried the official #ubuntukylin-devel irc, but no one is on.

Comment: UKUI is 20 times code  https://github.com/ukui .... Seems you can install UKUI with `sudo apt install ukui-desktop-environment` : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ukui-desktop-environment .. Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ukui&searchon=names

Comment: You can install ukui with the command Knud recommend, and we also have a temp PPA for testing the latest UKUI: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntukylin-members/ukui3.0 & sudo apt upgrade` (you should install some packages by hand for now, such as qt5-ukui-platformtheme). If you have other questions, you can submit a issue on the UKUI community page: https://github.com/ukui/community, Thanks!

Comment: @handsome_feng It is unclear what package should be installed after adding the PPA for an installation from scratch. I installed `ukui-desktop-environment` and this installed the old MATE-based version.

Comment: @DurandA you can refer to this: https://github.com/ukui/ukui-desktop-environment